# Somebody wrote a messages on tomcat Console

Tags: tomcat7

I've an application deployed on Tomcat 7, and this morning I noticed two messages on Tomcat console:

1. Did you see me on the stderr window?
2. Did you see me on the browser window as well?

Somebody managed to write remotely these messages. Do I have to be worried ? did somebody hack my website ?

thanks,

Frank

Comment: Cross site request: http://www.coderanch.com/t/610628/Tomcat/wrote-messages-tomcat-Console

Answer (score 5):

This is produced by a example jsp (webapps/examples/jsp/foo.jsp) with the following lines:

```
<eg:log>
Did you see me on the stderr window?
</eg:log>
```

Comment: ok...all clear now. Somebody tried to access the "examples" application. I will remove this Application.  Thanks !!

Comment: @user2023141 You should label the answer given by IsNull as correct since it has "solved" what you thought was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that is a standard Tomcat output message.

Comment: I don't think so, it's the first time since one year that I see such a message, and this doesn't look like a standard output message.

Comment: Well it is not a standard as such, but it is coming from the example foo.jsp once executed - See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you're running tomcat and go in the **localhost:8080/manager/html**, there's a site called **/examples** containing the following

```
Apache Tomcat Examples
Servlets examples
JSP Examples
WebSocket Examples
```

In the **JSP Examples**, if you go in the **Custom tag example**, a page will pop up with the following rendered in the browser:

```
Radio stations that rock:
98.5
92.3
107.7 Did you see me on the browser window as well?
```

The source code for this shows it's writing a log with a taglib prefix "eg" in the console:

```
<html>
<body>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tomcat.apache.org/example-taglib" prefix="eg"%>

Radio stations that rock:

<ul>
<eg:foo att1="98.5" att2="92.3" att3="107.7">
<li><%= member %></li>
</eg:foo>
</ul>

<eg:log>
Did you see me on the stderr window?
</eg:log>

<eg:log toBrowser="true">
Did you see me on the browser window as well?
</eg:log>

</body>
</html>
```